# OSXにインストールしたBlender 2.72bでコマンドラインから呼び出しするとエラー

Tags: macos, blender

OSX YosemiteにBlender 2.72をインストールし、コマンドラインから実行しようとしたところ、

```
$ blender -b test.blend -x 1 -o //text -F MPEG -s 0 -e 10 -a
```

以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
BLF_lang_init: 'locale' data path for translations not found, continuing
Warning! bundled python not found and is expected on this platform. 
(if you built with CMake: 'install' target may have not been built)
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Abort trap: 6
```

pythonが見つからないということなのですが、何が問題なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use blender command lines in OSX?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/how-to-use-blender-command-lines-in-osx)に対する、[Aldrikさんの返答](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2159)に答えがありました。

```
export BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON=/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.72/python
export BLENDER_SYSTEM_SCRIPTS=/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.72/scripts
export BLENDER_SYSTEM_DATAFILES=/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.72/datafiles
```

を~/.bash_profileあたりに書き込めば正常に動作します。

なお、`BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON`のみの指定だと、

```
found bundled python: /Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.72/python/
bpy: couldnt find 'scripts/modules', blender probably wont start.
```

という表示が出てしまいます。`BLENDER_SYSTEM_SCRIPTS`の指定は必須のようです。